# How to use where by second table Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I have the following query:

```
$objects = Object::with("prototypes");
```

As you can see I do request to model `Object` and join it with `prototypes`.

The `prototypes` table has structure:

```
prototype_id
name
```

How to make `where` in above query like as:

```
$objects = Object::with("prototypes")->where("prototype_id", 3);
```

Object model:

```
  public function prototypes()
 {
     return $this->belongsToMany('App\Prototype', 'object_prototype', 'object_id');
 }
```

Prototype model:

```
 public function objects(){
   return $this->belongsToMany("App\Object", "object_prototype", "prototype_id", "object_id");
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the relationship is correctly set in your Eloquent models, you can use the [`WhereHas`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) function to query relationship existence.

```
$objects = Object::with('prototypes')
    ->whereHas('prototypes', function ($query) {
        $query->where('prototype_id', 3);
    })
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add on @Jerodev answer.

> If you need even more power, you may use the `whereHas` and
>   `orWhereHas` methods to put "where" conditions on your has queries.
>   These methods allow you to add customized constraints to a
>   relationship constraint, such as checking the content of a comment:

```
// Retrieve all posts with at least one comment containing words like foo%
$posts = Post::whereHas('comments', function ($query) {
   $query->where('content', 'like', 'foo%');
})->get();
```

You can read more about [Eloquent Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships)

And in your case you can also construct a your query like.

```
Object::whereHas('prototypes', function ($query)){
  $query->where('prototype_id', 3);
})->get();
```

Comment: It does not work, because field `prototype_id` is not in Object Model

Comment: @Garaman i get you. Can you provide the relationship between those tables.

Comment: Updated question

Comment: Updated my answer